# Second time window.print not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I am using window.print() to provide print functionality in my web site. It's working fine in all browsers except safari browser. In safari browser on first click of print button it's working however if we cancel print dialog and again click on print button then it will ask user to allow print or not.

Below is my code for print button.

```
$("#btnPrint").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.print();
});
```